# dividir arreglo en 3 arreglos

Tags: javascript

tengo un arreglo que quiero dividir en 3 arreglos, de 4 en 4.

por ejemplo

```
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]
```

el resultado que quiero

```
[1,2,3,4,13,14,15,16,25,26,27,28]
[5,6,7,8,17,18,19,20,29,30,31,32]
[9,10,11,12,21,22,23,24,33,34,35,36]
```

esto hice

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36];
dividir(a);

function dividir(array) {
  let array1 = [];
  let array2 = [];
  let array3 = [];
  array.forEach(function(e, i) {
    if (i % 10 < 4) {
      array1.push(e);
    }
    if (i % 10 >= 4 && i % 10 < 8) {
      array2.push(e);
    }
    if (i % 10 > 7 && i % 10 < 12) {
      array3.push(e);
    }
  })
  console.log('TAMS', array1.length, array2.length, array3.length);
  return [array1, array2, array3];
}
```

Comment: Por lo que has puesto en el codigo podriamos intuir algunas cosas... Pero será mejor que nos indiques, cuales son las reglas para el arreglo y que caracteristicas deben tener los tres arreglos nuevos...

Comment: @NeryOrtez porfavor ve el ejemplo que puse, no tomes en cuenta mucho el codigo

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. ¿Qué significan los espacios que hacen como tres grupos en cada fila de los resultados esperados?

Comment: @A.Cedano puse los espacios para que entiendan, los quitare

Comment: se veía mejor con espacios `ABCDEFGHI -> 1: ADG 2: BEH 3: CFI`, cada letra 4 numeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que buscas es dividir el array en tres partes segun se dividan entre doce:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36];
dividir(a);

function dividir(array) {
  let array1 = [];
  let array2 = [];
  let array3 = [];
  array.forEach(function(e, i) {
    if (i % 12 < 4) {
      array1.push(e);
    } else if (/*i % 10 >= 4 &&*/ i % 12 < 8) {
      array2.push(e);
    } else if (/*i % 10 > 7 && */i % 12 < 12) {
      array3.push(e);
    }
  })
  console.log('TAMS', array1.length, array2.length, array3.length);
  return [array1, array2, array3];
}
```